# Qt GUI QTreeView/QTableView updating extremely slow

Tags: performance, qt, optimization, user-interface, qtreeview

I have isolated the slowness of QTableView/QTreeview updates to two places:

```
QStyledItemDelegate::paint()
Q_EMIT dataChanged()
```

I have tried many things, making the model's data method do virtually nothing but return a string.  The GUI is very crisp when there are few columns, say 10 or less.  My end user has huge 2560x1600 monitors and likes to maximze the view which can display over 50 columns and rows and is always complaing about how slow the GUI is.  Once the model is fully populated there are no insertions or deletions.  All I am doing is emitting `dataChanged()` as I get new updates at a reasonable rate, 2 times a second for each row, and about 48-100 row updates a second.

I have tried switching the graphics system to OpenGL this does not help.

- Commenting out only `dataChanged()` my CPU usage is is about 16%
- Commenting out only `QStyledItemDelegate::paint()` my cpu usage is about 30%
- Running with everything enabled it is 100%

Based on these statistics, I believe the slowness is somehow Qt related.  Is there a magical setting that will fix this?

Comment: how many times totally dataChanged() emitted per second?

Comment: About 48 to 100 per second.  Each dataChanged uses modelindex ranges sibling with row,0 to row,NumColumns

Answer (score -1):

Regarding what you wrote in an answer to my comment an answer is that you should refactor code which emit's dataChanged signals. There is no any sense in issue them more then 2-3 times a second. So you should accumulate changes in some kind of proxy/temporary storage and issue emit dataChanged separately based on timerEvent for example, so you will be guarantee with certain refresh rate without stressing CPU

Comment: I would do that if I could but it is a tree, and there are still at least 50+ distinct rows that may need to be emitted if the rows have different parents.

Comment: Don't want to go down that road of beginReset/endReset, it will lose the selection and tree expansion state. I have tried something similar with setUpdatesEnabled(), but the result was a clunky GUI and still doesn't answer the question of why does it take so long for Qt to render 50 x 75 cells at a reasonable framerate? Also at 1/10 of a second the CPU was pegged again using setUpdatesEnabled.

Comment: I think Qt controls are designed to be used in let's say some 'average' situations. I know why it stresses CPU a lot and etc.. I faced same problem several times, but I ended up once with beginReset/endReset and second time with making my own grid (for some real time monitoring software)..